# get parent category only

Tags: categories

Thanks to [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-only-child-categories-using-the_category), the snippet below will display a list child categories link only for each respective post if there's a child category for them.

```
<?php
  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    if ($category->category_parent  != 0) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr(strip_tags($category->name)) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
    }
  }
?>
```

Now I'm looking for a different snippet that'll display a list of parent categories only. Anyway how to get the parent category only?

Comment: Just reverse the `if` logic - instead of checking it *has* a parent, check that it doesn't i.e. `if ( ! $category->category_parent )`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$post = get_post(); // If $post is already available, skip.
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
    if ( $term->parent === 0 ) :
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'category' ) ) . 
            '" title="' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . 
            '</a> ';
    endif;
endforeach;
```